# Difference between XmlDocument and XDocument handling &#x0;

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have been trying to load a xml file which contains some null('&#x0') character. I have tried -

```
  XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
  document.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

and

```
XDocument.Load(stringReader);
```

`XmlDocument.LoadXml()` method successfully loads xml document whereas `XDocument.Load()` method gives `XmlException` for same xml string.

Sample Code to Reproduce :

```
string xmlFile = @"C:\dummyData.xml";

        string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile);

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(xmlString); //Work

        XDocument.Parse(xmlString); // Didn't work.

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
```

**Xml File**

[Copy the content of xml file from here](http://codeshare.io/S02Kt)

Comment: Are you trying to report bug (as both should fail) or you are looking for workaround or something else altogether?

Comment: The corresponding method to `document.LoadXml(xmlString)` would be `XDocument.Parse(xmlString)`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: First option is wokring actully, So my question is why XDocument cannot load a xml file which XmlDocument can load.

Comment: What does the XmlException say?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I did tried XDocument.Parse(xmlString), that din't work either.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

Comment: How exactly does the document contain that character? Is it a single `0x00` character (1 byte, like `\0` in code) or a `&#x0;` (5 bytes)?

Comment: @juharr depending how you use it `XmlReader` can read fron a file, URL or a string: essentially it uses a `StreamReader` and provides helpers to avoid you needing to explicitly create one.

Comment: @ThomasWeller : &#x0;

Comment: Does `XDocument.Load(stringReader)` work?

Comment: Can you write an SSCCE then? Should only be 5 lines of code to reproduce, right?

Comment: @juharr: No XDocument.Load(stringReader) didn't work, other one is working (i.e. XmlDocument. LoadXml)

Comment: Sounds like `XDocument.Load(xmlReader)` will work if you create an `XmlReader` with `XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters` set to `false`.

Comment: @juharr: Yes if i set CheckCharacters to false in XmlReaderSettings intance and give to create method of XmlReader then it works, but i don't need to do this if i use XmlDocument.LoadXml.

Comment: @Ramashankar Yes, but that's the difference here.  `XmlDocument.LoadXml` was designed to allow "bad" characters while `XDocument.Load` and `XDocument.Parse` where not.  You could argue over which is correct, but that's the work around to load your xml file into an `XDocument`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller : Added sample code and link to xml file in the question.

Comment: @Ramashankar: thanks, I have enhanced my answer according to the new input

Answer (score 4):

### Why &#x0; is a problem

As defined by W3C, [Entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references) are

```
CharRef ::=   '&#' [0-9]+ ';'
            | '&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ';'
```

So at first sight, an entity like `&#x0;` looks good.

But you need to read the definition:

> [Definition: A character reference refers to a specific character in the ISO/IEC 10646 character set, for example one not directly accessible from available input devices.]

So the character reference needs to point to ISO/IEC 10646 character, which is [linked](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wf-Legalchar):

> Characters referred to using character references MUST match the production for **Char**.

Luckily [Char](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets) is in the same document and defined as:

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

Therefore, as mentioned by [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) before, neither the C# `\0` character nor the escaped versions `&#x0;` or `&#0;` are allowed in XML documents.

### XML parser reality

Some parsers might ignore parts of above rules and not fully adhere to the standard.

### The real origin of the problem

The XML you posted seems to contain images/drawings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestData>
        <Images>
            <Drawings>
&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;ArrayOfMarkerState &gt;
&lt;/ArrayOfMarkerState&gt;
&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;</Drawings>
        </Images>
            <Date>2015-10-20T17:19:05.2656609+05:30</Date>
</TestData>
```

The nature of pixel graphics is that they contain binary data.

Developers who are not familiar with XML and faced with the problem of embedding binary data in XML will quickly *think* that any byte can be encoded as `&#x00;` ... `&#xFF;`.

Unfortunately this is plain wrong. Why? Well, because of the W3C definition above.

Other than that, this is even a bad idea regarding size. Even if it would work, a byte encoded like this will take 6 bytes in XML.

### Solving the original problem

Binary data cannot go into XML documents as XML entities, so let's find something that works and needs less than +500% increase of size.

The answer is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Base64 has a rough increase of +33% in size.

Encoding the 47 `&#x0;` bytes would result in

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
```

which is only 64 bytes long, compared to the original 235 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

A character reference `&#x0;` is not allowed in XML (at least XML 1.0 as supported by Microsoft). However for legacy support I think an `XmlTextReader` or an `XmlReader` created with `XmlReaderSettings` to not check characters can load such markup. `XmlDocument` uses such an XmlReader while XDocument does not.

Comment: Sure, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets which defines the characters as ` #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Does that means XmlDocument is simply ignoring such character whereas XDocument doesnot.

Comment: Side note: 0 is not valid for XML 1.1 either - http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets

Comment: Neither `XmlDocument` nor `XDocument` do the parsing of the XML itself, it is done by an `XmlReader` implementation. The one used by `LoadXml` of `XmlDocument` I think is a legacy `new XmlTextReader` where as the one used by `XDocument` is a normal one created with `XmlReader.Create` which implements the XML spec better.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yes, you are right, but I only remembered that XML 1.1 allows a couple of control characters as character references which XML 1.0 does not allow, so I was a bit vague in my text in the answer.

Comment: This also makes the XmlDocument incompatible for creating documents that get shipped to other XML readers.  It should have a "strict" mode for that purpose.  Another Microsoft fail.